# Horizontal listview navigation - visible item

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have more horizontal listview. For example let's take two of them. Items of each list are not the same length, when one list is scrolling - the other one does, too. I've solved that with contentX property. But, when I want to navigate between each other (when I press key "down" I need to force focus second listview). The problem is that focus is on horizontalna2.currentIndex that is remembered, and I want to go on first visible item in listview.

In android is that very simple, but to solve that here, huh..
Here is sketch of the code:

```
Rectangle {
width: 500
height: 200
ListModel {
        id: model1
        ListElement { itemwidth: 100 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 200 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 50 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 70 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: model2
        ListElement { itemwidth: 300 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 50 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 70 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 100 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 30 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
        ListElement { itemwidth: 90 }
    }

ListView {
    clip: true
    id: horizontalna
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    width: 500
    height: 60;
    focus: true
    model: model1
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    KeyNavigation.down: horizontalna2
    onContentXChanged: {
        if (horizontalna.activeFocus === true)
        {
            horizontalna2.contentX = horizontalna.contentX
        }
    }

    delegate: Item {
        id: containerHorizontal
        width: itemwidth; height: 60;

        Rectangle {
            id: contentHorizontal
            anchors.centerIn: parent; width: containerHorizontal.width; height: containerHorizontal.height - 10
            color: "transparent"
            antialiasing: true

            Rectangle { id: insideConHorizontal; anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 3; color: "grey"; antialiasing: true; radius: 5


                Text {
                    id: labelHorizontal
                    text: "name"
                    color: "white"
                }
            }
        }
        states: State {
            name: "active"; when: containerHorizontal.activeFocus
            PropertyChanges { target: contentHorizontal; color: "#FFFF00"; scale: 1}
            PropertyChanges { target: insideConHorizontal; color: "#F98F06" }
            PropertyChanges { target: labelHorizontal; color: "#0E2687"}
        }

    }
}
ListView {
    id: horizontalna2
    anchors.top: horizontalna.bottom
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    width: 500
    height: 60;
    focus: true
    model: model2
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal

    onContentXChanged: {
        if (horizontalna2.activeFocus === true)
        {
            horizontalna.contentX = horizontalna2.contentX

        }
    }
    delegate: Item {
        id: containerHorizontal2
        width: itemwidth; height: 60;

        Rectangle {
            id: contentHorizontal2
            anchors.centerIn: parent; width: containerHorizontal2.width; height: containerHorizontal2.height - 10
            color: "transparent"
            antialiasing: true

            Rectangle { id: insideConHorizontal2; anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 3; color: "grey"; antialiasing: true; radius: 5
                Text {
                    id:labelHorizontal2
                    color: "white"
                    text: "name"
                }
            }
        }
        states: State {
            name: "active"; when: containerHorizontal2.activeFocus
            PropertyChanges { target: contentHorizontal2; color: "#FFFF00"; scale: 1}
            PropertyChanges { target: insideConHorizontal2; color: "#F98F06" }
            PropertyChanges { target: labelHorizontal2; color: "#0E2687"}
        }
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT[SOLVED] :**
Get index of first visible item of second list depending on contentX --> function indexAt()

```
onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                    if (horizontalna.activeFocus === true)
                    {
                       horizontalna2.currentIndex = horizontalna2.indexAt((horizontalna2.contentX),0)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get index of first visible item of second list depending on contentX --> function indexAt()

```
onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                    if (horizontalna.activeFocus === true)
                    {
                       horizontalna2.currentIndex = horizontalna2.indexAt((horizontalna2.contentX),0)
                    }
                }
```